# Cython's cpython.datetime.datetime_new causes segmentation fault

Tags: python, datetime, cython

Cython's [`datetime.pyd`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/cpython/datetime.pxd#L119) exposes a `datetime_new` function, which is a wrapper around `datetime.h`'s [`PyDateTime_CAPI.DateTime_FromDateAndTime`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/datetime.h#L160). However, whenever I actually try to *use* this function, I get a segmentation fault immediately, even with valid values. Here is a minimal working example of Cython code:

```
cimport cpython.datetime

cpdef cpython.datetime.datetime construct_datetime():
    return cpython.datetime.datetime_new(2017, 12, 1, 12, 30, 15, 0, None)
```

Here is the `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(ext_modules = cythonize('test_segfault.pyx'))
```

And if I run it I get this:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace > /dev/null
$ $ python -c 'from test_segfault import construct_datetime; construct_datetime()'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm using Cython version 0.25.2 on Arch Linux, Python 3.6.1:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.version)'
3.6.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
```

Am I using this function wrong? I am aware that I can just call the standard `cpython.datetime.datetime` constructor here, but `datetime_new` bypasses the range checks, and I'm trying to see how much time the additional checks take.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to [initialize the datetime C API](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/0.25.2/Cython/Includes/cpython/datetime.pxd#L102):

```
# Datetime C API initialization function.
# You have to call it before any usage of DateTime CAPI functions.
cdef inline void import_datetime():
    PyDateTime_IMPORT
```

Comment: Sure did. Jeez. Somehow I got the impression that was already called by `cimport cpython.datetime`, but nope, that was just me being stupid. Thanks.